# My Android TabHost Is Crashing Will NullPointer Exception

Tags: android, tabs, crash

Hi I really need some help with my tabhost using android

the problem is that when I click on the list item that will launch the tab activity it crashes with no errors in the debugger or log cat.
The tab host is to have control of 3 or more activities and the tab widget is nested in a horizontal scrollview ... I know it's not the scrollview causing it to crash as it was crashing before I added it.

here's my code for the tab activity:

```
public class BulbaTab extends TabActivity {
TabHost tabHost;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tablay);

    // create the TabHost that will contain the Tabs
    tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    tabHost.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Dex Entry");
    tab1.setIndicator("Dex Entry");
    tab1.setContent(new Intent(this,Bulbasaur.class));

    TabHost.TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Moves List");
    tab2.setIndicator("Moves");
    tab2.setContent(new Intent(this,BulbasaurMovesList.class));

    TabHost.TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Evolution & Breeding");
    tab3.setIndicator("Evolution & Breeding");
    tab3.setContent(new Intent(this,BulbasaurBreeding.class));
    // Set the Tab name and Activity
    // that will be opened when particular Tab will be selected

    /** Add the tabs  to the TabHost to display. */
    tabHost.addTab(tab1);
    tabHost.addTab(tab2);
    tabHost.addTab(tab3);

}


}
```

And here's The Layout for the tabhost:

```
TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@android:id/tabhost"

  LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
TabWidget
HorizontalScrollView
FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        FrameLayout
LinearLayout
TabHost
```

had to remove tags as it wouldn't show on the site

here's the errors showing

```
           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.metaruptdonations.MetaDex/net.metaruptdonations.MetaDex.BulbaTab}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.metaruptdonations.MetaDex/net.metaruptdonations.MetaDex.Bulbasaur}: java.lang.NullPointerException
              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity  (ActivityThread.java:2305)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run   (ZygoteInit.java:1265)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.metaruptdonations.MetaDex/net.metaruptdonations.MetaDex.Bulbasaur}:
        java.lang.NullPointerException
               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2140)
               at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
               at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
               at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
               at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
               at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
               at net.metaruptdonations.MetaDex.BulbaTab.onCreate(BulbaTab.java:39)
               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
               at net.metaruptdonations.MetaDex.Bulbasaur.onCreate(Bulbasaur.java:48)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2140)
        at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
        at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
        at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
        at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
        at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
        at net.metaruptdonations.MetaDex.BulbaTab.onCreate(BulbaTab.java:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Comment: if anything crashes You will definitely get a crash report. I think You have to make some settings in Your logcat. Are You using eclipse or android studio..?

Comment: I'm using intellij IDEA 14 Ultimate, I have had errors show in the logcat before though so why would I need to change settings?

Comment: And maybe, I am not sure, You have to call tabhost.setup() directly before tabhost.addTab(); , not at the beginning..

Comment: There must be anything wrong in the settings if the app crahs and You get no output. Have You set a filter? Have You set it to Verbose ?

Comment: ok i'll try that in a sec :)

Comment: yep the log level is on Verbose

Comment: If this is not the problem, it also could be that something inside Your other Classes which You setting to the tabs..

Comment: I have tested your code and It works correctly...Are you sure that tabs are the problem? Anyway review your log cat because it must have an error.
Post the code when you call BuscaTab.class

Comment: I have run your code, it's working fine..There is no problem with your code.I think you forgot to declare `BulbaTab` activity in your manifest..Check once

Comment: ok there's an error showing now that I moved the tabHost.setup(); to just before the add tabs and its giving a null pointer when trying to start the activity to be content view

Comment: @Prasad BulbaTab is declared in the manifest but it still crashes I'm just now wondering what's wrong,

Comment: Can You please post this error?

Comment: The problem seems to be in Your BulbaSur class, please post this class and mark line 48...

Comment: I've fixed the launch activity problem but now I have to fix my horizontal scroll view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HorizontalScrollView can have only one childview you need to change your xml like this

```
 <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >


   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

  </TabHost>
```

Comment: but it only has one child view its only wrapping the tab widget, if I were to do it like that then my content view would then have a horizontal scrollview in it which I don't need, it is also didn't crash it originally when I first started making the layout for it? but thanks :)

Comment: ok so if I were to place a linear layout around just the tab widget will that be ok?

Comment: yes. if you want horizontalScrollView for tabs or tabhost?

Comment: only want it for the tabs themselves so that when I add more it doesn't clutter

Comment: oh I think I know why the action bar is still in my child content view i'll see if it fixes it

Comment: ok well it's working now but the tabs aren't displaying anything from the layout files linked with the activity

Comment: yep I updated it now its working but the horizontal scroll is now the whole layout

Comment: if you want horizontalScrollview for your tabs. you need not add tabhost. you need to add each activities (Bulbasaur)layout.

Comment: remove tabhost child horizontalScrollView. I updated the xml.